# How to stream very large file to s3 from url using boto3 and Python?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I would like to stream large files directly (by division into smaller parts) from an url directing to a server where data is located, to S3 bucket on AWS. I want to do this, to avoid saving extremely large files on a temporary EC2 instance, that will perform this operation. Currently I try to this in the following way:

(Currently for testing I download smaller exemplary csv file)

```
link = "https://www.stats.govt.nz/assets/Uploads/Annual-enterprise-survey/Annual-enterprise-survey-2021-financial-year-provisional/Download-data/annual-enterprise-survey-2021-financial-year-provisional-csv.csv"
session = requests.Session()
response = session.get(link)
s3_bucket = "my-bucket-name"
s3_file_path = "file-path-to-my-file/data1.csv"
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
response.raw.decode_content = True
conf = boto3.s3.transfer.TransferConfig(multipart_threshold=2, max_concurrency=4)
s3.upload_fileobj(response.raw, s3_bucket, s3_file_path, Config=conf)
```

Unfortunately, when I execute this code, a file is created on S3, but it contains 0 bytes of data.
Would anyone be kind enough to point the road to the right solution?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is using:

```py
session = requests.Session()
response = session.get(link)
```

which returns: `<class 'requests.models.Response'>`

It then uses:

```py
response.raw.decode_content = True
...response.raw...
```

However, the output of `response.raw` is of type `<class 'urllib3.response.HTTPResponse'>`

Instead, it should use `response.content`, which will return the content of the request.

**Tip:** It can be handy to print things like `type(response.raw)` when debugging.